# How to add a full width area in the homepage with 2 columns with right bar?

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks

I'd like to add a **full-width area** (in order to insert a block) in my Magento homepage which is now set to `2 columns with right bar` layout.

Should I add a new section before the main content? How? Or is there a better way without getting layout shifting?

[image]

Comment: do you want full width on all the pages or only on homepage?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya I'd like it only on homepage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply went on the Magento backend in `Content -> Widgets -> Add Widget`, Type `Static Block` and  in `Layout Updates` I chose `Display on: Specified Page`, then `CMS Home Page` and `Before Main Columns`, and selected the block. That's it!

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, you need to do this things.

1. Create one page with empty layout.
2. Set those page width 100%.
3. Now set this newly created page as homepage.

Comment: Then, how can I set below the main content and the side content if I create one page with a 100% width?

Comment: Using the layout container.

Comment: Could you provide more details?